# Replacing a substring of a TextNode with an HTML node (element)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to iterate a set of textNodes and replacing some occurrences with an HTML element.

For example:

```
<span>some text<br>without html nodes</span>
```

Translates to

- Node1: Type Text     `"some text"`
- Node2: Type Element: `<br>`
- Node3: Type Text:    `"without html nodes"`

How do I modify for example node 3 into:

- Node3: Type Text     `"without"`
- Node4: Type Element  `<span>html</html>`
- Node5: Type Text     `"nodes"`

So, basically I want to replace a substring of a textnode and convert it into an html node. Any ideas?

Comment: `span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace('html','<span>html</span>')`

Comment: are the values of Node 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 a constant string or its a variable ?

Comment: maybe show how you get those textnodes

Comment: I m getting the nodes through element.childNodes

Comment: @adeneo With your suggestion, If there are two or more instances of "html" in the text, they will also be replaced. I'm relying on the index positions and lengths.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa They're variables, taken from element.childNodes for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) interface provides a lot of convenient node slicing and splicing operations

```
let span = document.createElement("span")
span.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "some text<br>without html nodes") 
let text = span.childNodes[2]
let range = new Range()
range.setStart(text, 8)
range.setEnd(text, 12)
range.surroundContents(document.createElement("span"))
console.log(span.outerHTML) // prints <span>some text<br>without <span>html</span> nodes</span>
```

To compute the particular offsets in the text node you can use various string or regexp methods.